# Regex to not allow multiple special chars in a row

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that will not allow multiple special characters in a row.

For example:

'this is a test' = valid input
'this, is a test' = valid input
'.......' = not valid input
'this,, is a test' = not valid input

Comment: Have you tried creating one, or do you not know how to start? What counts as a "special" character?

Comment: i probably should have pointed that out.  For this one, 'special' characters are ,._-'"

Comment: @AarronH, `;` is not special? Nor `}`, `¤`, `ÿ`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how you define "special characters", you can use:

```
var valid = !str.match(/[^a-z0-9\s]{2}/i);
```

---

Updated after specs:

> For this one, 'special' characters are `,._-'"`

```
var valid = !str.match(/[-,._'"]{2}/i);
```

Comment: @AarronH: note that this will classify a string like `{{{{{{` as "valid".

Comment: I am first having it go through another filter Regex that will see if it contains a-zA-Z0-9 and only the special characters I have listed. Then it will go through this filter to see if there are multiple 'special' chars in a row

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a regular expression to do this?

```
 var is_special_character = function(ch) { ... }

 var is_valid = function(str) {
   var special_characters = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
     if(is_special_character(str[i]))
       special_characters++;
     else  
       special_characters = 0;
     if(special_characters > 1) return false;
   }
   return true;
 }
```

Comment: Also define `is_special_character()` without regex, then compare to my answer and you'll have the answer to your question. ;-)

Comment: @Qtax, I can define `is_special_character` without regex :)

Comment: @Alexander: quite easily, actually (`specials.indexOf(ch) >= 0`)